# PHP PDO SQLSRVR high cpu usage on Database

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, pdo, odbc

I'm facing a strange problem after reinstall Ubuntu Server 18.04.

My **"Server 1"** had these packages and drivers to connect PHP-FPM + Apache with a **remote** Sql Server Database 2016, the connections are using IPv4.

```sh
$ odbcinst --version

unixODBC 2.3.7
```

```sh
$ apt list msodbcsql17

msodbcsql17/bionic,now 17.7.2.1-1 amd64 [installed]
```

```sh
$ php --re pdo_sqlsrv | head -1

Extension [ <persistent> extension #33 pdo_sqlsrv version 5.9.0 ]
```

```sh
$ php --re sqlsrv | head -1

Extension [ <persistent> extension #41 sqlsrv version 5.9.0 ]
```

Below are my */etc/odbcinst.ini* content:

```sh
$ cat /etc/odbcinst.ini

[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.7.so.2.1
UsageCount=1
```

```sh
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

My two servers are Ubuntu 18.04, all packages are upgraded.

To clarify, we are no issues on Ubuntu side, the issues are on SQL Server.

Using my **"Server 1"**, Linux and SQL Server are ok and fast.

But using my **"Server 2"**, with a new Ubuntu 18.04 install, my SQL Server use more than 90% CPU, and Linux still fast.

These two Linux uses the same packages and drivers listed above, with exactly same versions.

The PHP code executed are exactly same on two servers.

I forget to look another package or config on my **"Server 2"**?

I don't know if have relation, but on my SQL Server, the ODBC Driver version is 13. Maybe not, because the **"Server 1"** does not cause issues.

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, the same queries are run from server1 and server2 with purportedly the same software but the same remote SQL Server shows high CPU only for those run from server2. This may be due to different execution plans. I suggest you examine the plans to see if they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem!

**Fast answer**

Reading [trace log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-trace/sql-trace?view=sql-server-ver15) on SQL Server, on "Application Name" field, we can observe that some origins calls DataBase (Apache, PHP-FPM and PHP Freetds)

The issue occurs using [PHP SQLSRV](https://pecl.php.net/package/pdo_sqlsrv) (pdo), with only with FreeTDS (php ext DBLIB) does not have problem.

Then is a good idea use only [PHP DBLIB](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) with [FreeTDS](https://www.freetds.org/) on unix systems.

**Complete answer**

**TL;DR;**

Of course, the problem is not with only with PHP SQLSRV extension. On our investigation, we look at diver version, and client Linux uses newest version of driver [MSODBCSQL17](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

But on our server, running SQL SERVER 2016, the driver version is 13.
[image: SQL Server 2016 - ODBC Driver]

But the Microsoft have a [upgrade to version 17](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) (same used on Linux client)

Reading the change log, an [issue about high cpu usage is fixed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/bug-fixes?view=sql-server-ver15#bug-fixes-in-the--odbc-driver-17-for-).

***"Can you prove?"***

Yes!

We didi a simple test, on our linux "server 1", we remove support from freetds (disable DBLIB), and immediately we can observe a decrease performance on our dashboard, and after some minutes, when freetds is enabled again (DBLIB) the performance returns to normal, see above.

[image]

Our new linux does not have freetds installed, we only taken drivers from Microsoft to PHP 7+ and PECL extension.

The problem is because our SQL SERVER uses ODBC Driver 13 and our cliente have ODBC Driver 17.

We can not upgrade the driver on SQL SERVER, because we need this version, and ODBC 17 is supported only on SQL SERVER 2019.

Then, for now our solution is to use freetds  and not PHP SQLSRV extension.

Another point to observe is, all query from PHP SQLSRV is [parametrized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-prepexec-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) like this:

```sql
Declare @Out int;  
EXEC sp_prepexec @Out output,   
    N'@P1 nvarchar(128), @P2 nvarchar(100)',  
    N'SELECT database_id, name  
      FROM sys.databases  
      WHERE name=@P1 AND state_desc = @P2',   
          @P1 = 'tempdb', @P2 = 'ONLINE';   
EXEC sp_unprepare @Out;
```

The same query with freetds appears on tracer log like this:

```sql
SELECT database_id, name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name='tempdb' AND state_desc='ONLINE';
```

I think that this difference makes SQL SERVER force use more CPU than FreeTDS with more simple query.

**But you have installed both, how to decide wich to use?**

Yes, on my "server 1" we have both drivers and extensions installed, but my application decide to use first DBLIB is is available, we use [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), and this code is inside [connector](https://github.com/jimrubenstein/laravel-framework/blob/f7ba54c132319631163ac0c98101da0a3b16c3ca/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/SqlServerConnector.php#L35):

```php
/**
 * Create a DSN string from a configuration.
 *
 * @param  array   $config
 * @return string
 */
protected function getDsn(array $config)
{
    // First we will create the basic DSN setup as well as the port if it is in
    // in the configuration options. This will give us the basic DSN we will
    // need to establish the PDO connections and return them back for use.
    if (in_array('dblib', $this->getAvailableDrivers())) {
        return $this->getDblibDsn($config);
    } elseif ($this->prefersOdbc($config)) {
        return $this->getOdbcDsn($config);
    } else {
        return $this->getSqlSrvDsn($config);
    }
}
```

**Conclusion**

I didn't knows that my applications still using FreeDTS after install PHP SQLSRV, this problem did not appears before, cause laravel have a preference to dblib.

This problem is too hard to find, and I hope that all analysis helps you, who is reading until this line.

Thx!

;)